# Open Console From A File

Tags: c++, console

very noob question here.

I am making an application in visual studio that does not open the console. However, I would like to make an event linked to a button to open the console and start outputting data in it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB net:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

`Public Class Form1`

```
Public Class Win32
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Public Shared Function AllocConsole() As Boolean

    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Public Shared Function FreeConsole() As Boolean

    End Function
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Win32.AllocConsole()
    Console.WriteLine("Hey, I opened the console!")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Win32.FreeConsole()
End Sub
End Class
```